# Creating a hexadecimal NumericUpDown control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created a hexadecimal NumericUpDown control by sub-classing the basic NumericUpDown and adding the following method:

```
protected override void UpdateEditText()
{
  this.Text = "0x" + ((int) Value).ToString("X2");
}
```

This works pretty well. The control now shows values in the format:

> 0x3F

which is exactly what I was after.

But one thing bothers me: every time the **Text**-property is assigned, a **System.FormatException** is thrown. This doesn't seem to affect the control's functionality, but still I think it's ugly.

This is the top of the callstack:

> > MyAssembly.dll!HexNumericUpDown.UpdateEditText() Line 31    C#
> >         System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown.ValidateEditText()  Unknown
> >         System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.UpDownBase.Text.set(string value) Unknown

Can I just ignore this exception? Or is there a clean way to get rid of this?

Comment: Do you maybe have something running on the TextChanged event that tries to convert the string back to an integer?

Comment: "every time the Text-property is assigned, a System.FormatException is thrown" but where? Post the stacktrace.

Comment: Done. I've added the stack trace.

Comment: The text *is* invalid. You should override [ValidateEditText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.validateedittext(v=vs.110).aspx) and allow hexadecimal strings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to override the ValidateEditText() method so you can properly handle the (optional) "0x" prefix.  And override UpdateEditText() to prefix "0x".  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class HexUpDown : NumericUpDown {
    public HexUpDown() {
        this.Hexadecimal = true;
    }

    protected override void ValidateEditText() {
        try {
            var txt = this.Text;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt)) {
                if (txt.StartsWith("0x")) txt = txt.Substring(2);
                var value = Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToInt32(txt, 16));
                value = Math.Max(value, this.Minimum);
                value = Math.Min(value, this.Maximum);
                this.Value = value;
            }
        }
        catch { }
        base.UserEdit = false;
        UpdateEditText();
    }

    protected override void UpdateEditText() {
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(this.Value);
        this.Text = "0x" + value.ToString("X4");
    }
}
```

Fwiw, the quirky try/catch-em-all comes straight from the .NET version.  I kept it to make the control behave the same way.  Tweak the ToString() argument the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Difference between casting and ConvertTo:

`(int)obj` - this is an explicit cast of obj to the type int, you are telling the compiler that obj is an int. If obj is not a int type, you will get a cast exception. But it is not **REALLY** an int. and the X2 format needs real ints.

`Convert.ToInt32(obj)` - This is an explicit call to the Convert class to return a **int representation** of obj.

Because of that you need to use `Convert.ToInt32(Value)`

**BUT** in MSDN it says:

> 1)This API (numericUpDown.Text) supports the .NET Framework
>   infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.
>
> 2)The Text has no affect on the appearance of the NumericUpDown
>   control; therefore, it is hidden in the designer and from
>   IntelliSense.

Comment: That does not solve the problem. The exception occurs when the value is assigned to the property Text. The int-casting does not cause an exception.

Comment: this.Text, what is "this"?

Comment: This is the NumericUpDown control.

Comment: I Edited the answer, becuase it's a little long for comment

Answer (score 0):

I guess you also need to override the <strike>[ParseEditText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.parseedittext.aspx)</strike> [ValidateEditText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.validateedittext.aspx) method, to accept the hex value and set the Value property to the correct int value.

Comment: `ParseEditText` isn't virtual but ValidateEditText is